# Eclipse code completion broken when using XFCE

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, xfce

I recently switched to using XFCE in Ubuntu 14 because I noticed that Eclipse runs much, much faster.

However, code completion stopped working all together.

Using the menu **Edit > Content Assist > ...** path still works as expected, but typing Ctrl-space does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is that IBus settings has seized control of the `Ctrl-space` hot key for its own "Next input" function.

Open **Settings > Keyboard Input Methods** dialog and change the **Next Input** hot key setting to anything else. I chose `Ctrl-0`

[image]